# get size of array or string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to loop through a dictionary to get the size of each element associated with each of the keys.  These dictionary elements are either arrays or a string.  If its a string i need the number of characters in the string.  If its an array, I need the size of the array.

```
import numpy as np
myDict = {'string':  'this is a string', 'arraySingle': np.array(12),
          'array1': np.array([12]), 'multiarray': np.array((12, 12))}
for key in myDict.keys():
    size = np.size(myDict[key])  
    try:
        length = len(myDict[key])
    except TypeError:
        length = None
    print('key "{}" has a length of {} and a size of {} '.format(key, length, size))
```

produces

```
key string has a length of 16 and a size of 1 
key arraySingle has a length of None and a size of 1 
key array1 has a length of 1 and a size of 1 
key multiarray has a length of 2 and a size of 2
```

What i would really like is an answer of:

```
key "string" has a ___ of 16 
key "arraySingle" has ___ of 1
key "array1" has a ___ of 1 
key "multiarray" has a ___ of 2
```

how do I get that answer elegantly ?  I would like to do it in one line as opposed to  use something like

```
if isisntance(myDict[key], str):
   print("do something")
elif isinstance(myDict[key], np.ndarray):
   print("do something else")
```

Comment: I don't think you mean "key" here.

Comment: I wonder why `len` doesn't work on `np.array`?  That seems odd, except for that fact that numpy allows multiple dimensions.

Comment: fair point Mark, i tried to clarify "key".  to your second comment, i have noooo idea....  interesting problem though

Comment: `len` on an array returns the first dimension.  For a 1d array that would be the same as `size`.  There's nothing wrong with having several `instance` tests or try/except.  That's commonly done in Python and `numpy` code.  Package those tests in an function is you want to keep your code "clean".

Comment: However a 0d array, with 1 scalar value, will not have a `len`.   It's not iterable.  `np.array(1)` vs `np.array([1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but I think this will help solve your question:

```
import numpy as np
myDict = {'string':  'this is a string', 'array': np.array((12))}
for key in myDict.keys():
    try:
        length = len(myDict[key])
        length_type = 'length' 
    except TypeError:
        length = np.size(myDict[key])
        length_type = 'size' 

    print('key "{}" has a {} of {}'.format(key, length_type, length))
```

output:

```
key "string" has a length of 16
key "array" has a size of 1
```

Comment: this is disappointing, but the best answer so far, i'll award

Comment: @SBFRF I am not sure if you can do anything significantly different. They are different data types and hence require a checking statement somehow. Was the output not what you were looking for? maybe you can elaborate more on your desired output and we can try to help better.  Also, thank you for the accept :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have complicated logic that you want to clear out of the way, package it into its own function.

```
def size(x):
    if isinstance(x, np.array):
        return np.size(x)
    try:
        return len(x)
    except TypeError:
        return 1

print('key "{}" has a size of {}'.format(key, size(myDict[key])))
```